# Python + pygtk generate table of checkboxes from database

Tags: python, mysql, checkbox, gtk, pygtk

I'm working on a project were I want to load data from a MySQL database and display it in a PyGTK application for easy overview and configuration. My goal is for the program to automaticly add new rows depending on the database contents, ie. if I add a new command to the database, I should not need to make any changes to my GTK-application.

This is my testing database:

```
+----+----------+---------+----+--------+
| id | name     | enabled | op | desc   |
+----+----------+---------+----+--------+
|  1 | !help    |       1 |  0 | blabla |
|  2 | !version |       1 |  1 | blabla |
|  3 | !tp      |       0 |  1 | blabla |
+----+----------+---------+----+--------+
```

And I would like to (dynamicly) create a GTK-application that looks something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNjiB.png

I've some experience working with python before but not so much GTK, and I'm not sure how to approach this problem. Could someone give me a working example?

Regards Oscar

Comment: What platform are you targeting (Windows, Linux)? GTK2, GTK3? PyGTK is only for GTK2...

Comment: Python 2.7, GTK2. Using both Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this.  I'll leave you to fill in the details, like the MySQL stuff.  The important part here, to make the widgets look evenly spaced is the parameter

```
gtk.HBox(homogeneous=True)
```

otherwise they will be all over the place, only taking up as much room as they require to display themselves.

Hope this is what you're after.

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require20()
import gtk

data = [['1', '!help',    '1', '0', 'blabla'], 
        ['2', '!version', '1', '1', 'blabla'], 
        ['3', '!tp',      '0', '1', 'blabla']]

def main():
    window = gtk.Window()
    window.set_title('Dynamic controls')
    window.connect("delete_event", gtk.main_quit)

    vbox = gtk.VBox()
    window.add(vbox)

    for row in data:
        hbox = gtk.HBox(homogeneous=True)
        hbox.pack_start(gtk.Label(row[1]))
        enabled_checkbox = gtk.CheckButton('Enabled')
        enabled_checkbox.set_active(row[2] is '1')
        hbox.pack_start(enabled_checkbox)
        op_checkbox = gtk.CheckButton('OP')
        op_checkbox.set_active(row[3] is '1')
        hbox.pack_start(op_checkbox)
        hbox.pack_start(gtk.Label(row[4]))
        vbox.pack_start(hbox)


    window.show_all()
    gtk.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hello James, Thanks a bunch for this. Exactly what I was looking for. I knew there would be some really simple way to do it :)

Is it possible to also loop though the vbox-rows to get the current state from the checkboxes and generate a new list with data?

Comment: Example: I tick "Enabled" for !tp and press apply somewhere, then the program would create a new list were row 3 would be like this: ['3', '!tp', '1', '1', 'blabla']
Thanks once more for a great solution.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You can add change event listeners to the CheckButton if that helps.

Comment: Im trying to build a management-application for these database-entries. My idea is to load the current values from the database, and be able to change them using the checkboxes, hit a apply button and write the changes back to database.

Comment: It would be possible to iterate through the checkbuttons, but you would be better off setting up a separate data structure and altering the values in this structure using callbacks on the toggle event of the checkbutton passing the callback some data to identify the checkbutton. ie enabled_checkbox.connect("toggled", callback, "check button 1") with the callback having the signature def callback(self, widget, data=None) and you can use data to identify which row you're editing.  You can then scan this later with the apply and apply the result to the database

Comment: Or you could, using the identifying data alter the database directly, using the data passed to the callback function to id the row in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Use **libgda**. It gives you tree models that are automatically tied to database contents.

Comment: Here's an example of `GdauiDataGrid` from the libgda website: http://www.gnome-db.org/CodeExampleGrid And here's the API documentation for the UI components: http://developer.gnome.org/libgda/stable/ch22.html